# android: how to calculate distance between two points

Tags: java, android, google-maps, distance

I want to calculate distance between two points. I googled it but all I found are shortest path distance which I do not want I want to know the road distance between two points.

Comment: I bet you have to find the route first, then - if not provided - calculate manualy all distances between every points.

Comment: You need to use the google maps API to get directions first, then it will tell you the distance using the route determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={start_address}&daddr={destination_address}

it will give in direction detail along with distance and time in between two locations

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=79.7189,72.3414&daddr=66.45,74.6333&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [google maps api for directions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

You can use a petition with a response as Json setting the parameter in the request.

http:// maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/**json**?origin=40.484037,-3.673553&destination=40.419508,-3.693466&sensor=false&units=metric

or as an XML

http:// maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/**xml**?origin=40.484037,-3.673553&destination=40.419508,-3.693466&sensor=false&units=metric

you can set **origin** and **destiny** values as your start and end point in the **mode** that you want, walking, bicycle, driving...

then set the **units** in **metrics** or **imperial**.

On the returning JSON or XML you can parse the information that you need.

You can also set way points like the example on the MAPS API.

On the legs TAG the first distance will be the total distance between the two points.

```
 "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "11,7 km",
                  "value" : 11661
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "16 min",
                  "value" : 941
               },
```

You can parse all the information that you need in no time :)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the google direction APIs have changed a bit.

Here are the new ones:

- For JSON, [use](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.46,77.08&destination=28.44,77.03&sensor=false&units=metric).
- For XML, [use](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=28.46,77.08&destination=28.44,77.03&sensor=false&units=metric).